# Exponential function negative: $\left(\frac{81}{4}\right)^{1/4}\left(\frac{1}4\right)^{-3/4}$

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation, fractions

This is another example. $\left(\dfrac{81}{4}\right)^{1/4}\left(\dfrac{1}4\right)^{-3/4}$

Multiply on both sides equals  $\dfrac{81^{1/4}}{4^{1/4}}\cdot \dfrac{1^{-3/4}}{4^{-3/4}}$

This should be $\dfrac{3}{4^{1/4}}\cdot \dfrac{1^{-3/4}}{4^{-3/4}}$ which I get to -3/$\sqrt 4^{-1/2}$

Is that correct? I should get the answer 6.

Comment: How the quack did you get a minus from all positive expressions? It's clearly $3/4^{-1/2}=3/(1/2)=6$.

Comment: Yes i screwed up

Answer (score 2):

Think I got the answer now. $$\frac{3}{2^{-1}} = 3 \cdot 2 = 6.$$

Comment: Your answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way (bring everything under a single exponent):
$$(\frac{81}{4})^\frac 14 \cdot (\frac{1}{4})^\frac {-3}{4} = (\frac{81}{4})^\frac 14 \cdot [(\frac 14)^{-3}]^{\frac 14} = (\frac{81}{4})^\frac 14 \cdot(4^{3})^{\frac 14}  = (\frac{81}{4}\cdot 64)^{\frac 14} = (81 \cdot 16)^{\frac 14} = 3 \cdot 2 = 6$$